# Best algorithm for detecting interior and exterior angles of an arbitrary shape in python

Tags: python, algorithm, geometry

I have been working on a 2-dimensional object creator program in python 3.2.5 that handles manipulations of arbitrary shapes and calculates collision detection between them. The program allows you to input a shape's coordinates, and from there it will do whatever else you want it to do (draw the shape to the screen, expand the border, manipulate individual coordinates, make it symmetrical, etc.).

But I've run into a problem when trying to calculate the interior angles of an arbitrary polygon. While the algorithm's I've used to calculate the angles technically output the correct angle, I have no way of telling whether or not the program spits out an interior angle or an exterior angle (since the arbitrary shape the user inputs could have concave vertices).

On paper this would seem like a piece of cake, since you can visualize the shape and you can interpret which angle is interior and exterior automatically. But since the program only stores the values of the coordinates and doesn't actually visually create the object to extrapolate data, this problem becomes a little bit trickier to solve.

So my question is:

What method should I use to calculate the angle between two lines and how should I go about using it to determine the difference between an interior and an exterior angle?

For example, if I have a shape that has coordinates ((30,50),(35,47),(40,50),(37,43),(35,35),(33,43)) (which ends up looking sort of like an upside-down spire with a concave base), I can easily calculate the angles between the lines, but which angle I am calculating is a mystery.

Comment: Do you know how to check if two lines make a left turn or a right turn? This is for example used in graham scan.

Comment: I guess you were having difficulty because your polygons are not regular and can be convex. I tried graphing the points you gave -  https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qus4esg5tg 
say, A=(35,35) B=(33,43) C=(30,50) D=(40,50) E=(35,47) F=(37,43)
We can construct ABCDEF, ABCEDF and ABECDF as polygons. In each polygon there are internal angles greater than 180 degrees. The method suggested by @kalhartt might be the best one?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As Jesse suggested, you first need to keep the list of vertices in some order. I will suggest counter-clockwise. Use the dot product to find the angle and the sign of the cross product to tell you which side it is. For storing them in counterclockwise order, positive will be the inner angle

```
# Its a square with the top edge poked in
points = [
    ( 1.0,  1.0),
    ( 0.0,  0.0),
    (-1.0,  1.0),
    (-1.0, -1.0),
    ( 1.0, -1.0)]


def angle(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    # Use dotproduct to find angle between vectors
    # This always returns an angle between 0, pi
    numer = (x1 * x2 + y1 * y2)
    denom = sqrt((x1 ** 2 + y1 ** 2) * (x2 ** 2 + y2 ** 2))
    return acos(numer / denom) 


def cross_sign(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    # True if cross is positive
    # False if negative or zero
    return x1 * y2 > x2 * y1

for i in range(len(points)):
    p1 = points[i]
    ref = points[i - 1]
    p2 = points[i - 2]
    x1, y1 = p1[0] - ref[0], p1[1] - ref[1]
    x2, y2 = p2[0] - ref[0], p2[1] - ref[1]

    print('Points', p1, ref, p2)
    print('Angle', angle(x1, y1, x2, y2))
    if cross_sign(x1, y1, x2, y2):
        print('Inner Angle')
    else:
        print('Outer Angle')
    print('')
```

Comment: Also, use the following modified angle function to get the angle value in degrees. 
`
def angle(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    # Use dotproduct to find angle between vectors
    # This always returns an angle between 0, pi
    numer = (x1 * x2 + y1 * y2)
    denom = sqrt((x1 ** 2 + y1 ** 2) * (x2 ** 2 + y2 ** 2))
    return acos(numer / denom)  * 180 / PI
`

Answer (score 6):

The gold standard for finding the signed angle between two vectors is `atan2(cross(a,b)), dot(a,b))`. High accuracy and robustness at all angles. (In 2D, `cross` is the perpendicular dot product, `ax*by-ay*bx`. In three dimensions, use the length of the cross product; its direction is your axis of rotation.)

Some things NOT to do:

- Anything involving `acos`. Arccosine is a code smell. It suffers from limited range, won't give you signs, needs manual argument clamping, and has poor precision at its extrema. If you find yourself using it, try something else.
- Anything involving line slopes. Poor accuracy, and of course is undefined for vertical vectors.
- Manually choosing an angular range based on extra tests. This is likely to lead to discontinuities near the axes.

Comment: Here is some numpy code to implement @Sneftel's solution. `def angle(a, b):
    return np.arctan2(np.cross(a, b), np.dot(a, b))`

Comment: What are a,b in this example? Tuples? Vectors? x,y coords?

Comment: @GrimSqueaker a and b are the two vectors.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what algorithms you've tried, but typically this problem is solved by storing the list of points in the same order (say, clockwise) so that every time run your angle-calculation on a triple of points *in order*, you always get the same side of the shape (say, the interior angle).

Comment: I've tried using an algorithm that calculates the slopes of the two adjacent lines to calculate the angle when they meet. The calculation then becomes math.atan((slope1-slope2)/(1+slope1*slope2)), which will spit out the angle. Which angle it spits out I'm not entirely sure. I was wondering if I should actually run a calculation to find which slope is greater, and subtract the smaller one from the greater one in the numerator, but from what I've researched that wouldn't work.

Comment: Ah! In this case, you need atan2, since atan doesn't have enough information to give you the right signed angle.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple algorithm for checking if a point exists inside of a polygon. Found [here](http://www.ecse.rpi.edu/~wrf/Research/Short_Notes/pnpoly.html), he also gives a pretty good description of how it works.  The following is written in C but can easily be converted to python.

```
int pnpoly(int nvert, float *vertx, float *verty, float testx, float testy)
 {
  int i, j, c = 0;
   for (i = 0, j = nvert-1; i < nvert; j = i++) {
    if ( ((verty[i]>testy) != (verty[j]>testy)) &&
 (testx < (vertx[j]-vertx[i]) * (testy-verty[i]) / (verty[j]-verty[i]) + vertx[i]) )
       c = !c;
  }
  return c;
}
```

Anyway you could use this algorithm to check if a vertex is concave or convex by checking it against the polygon without the test vertex.

so if you had a quadrilateral with vertexes a,b,c,d and you wanted to see if b is convex or concave you can test if b is inside triangle a,c,d.  If it is inside it's convex, if not concave, and if neither not a vertex at all.

With the knowledge of weather it is convex or concave you should be able to parse out which is the interior angle and which is the exterior.